# Auto increment an ID with a string prefix in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have created the following table and I wish to have the userID auto-increment whenever there is a row added to the database. However I would like the ID to be formatted as 000001 for example as below, since there are a few tables and it would be ideal to give each ID a string prefix:

```
userID
----------
user000001
user000002
user000003


CREATE TABLE UserTable (
userID VARCHAR(20),
username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pkUserID
    PRIMARY KEY (userID),
CONSTRAINT uniUsername
    UNIQUE (username)
);
```

Comment: rethink your PK. why is the "user" word necessary ?

Comment: I thought it would be useful since I have lots of tables and having the string prefixing the ID would help know which table the ID is from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use a combination of trigger and sequence as shown in the code below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CREATE SEQUENCE usertable_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER usertable_trigger  
BEFORE INSERT ON UserTable
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT 'user' || to_char(usertable_seq.NEXTVAL, '000099')
  INTO   :new.userID
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The prefix `user` is absolute pointless because it is attached to every ID. Drop it and use an `ID NUMBER` only. Plus, follow Jugal's advice.