# How to prefix no of zeros with a variable data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle sequence `test` as`CREATE  SEQUENCE test START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999 NOCYCLE NOORDER;` and i have to insert N number of records into a table with value `10D00001` however for each record the last 5 digits should be incremented. For an example

```
insert into test1 values('10D00001');
insert into test1 values('10D00002');
insert into test1 values('10D00003');
insert into test1 values('10D00004');
... N
```

Can anyone help me how to prefix `n` no of `0` if the sequence value is less than 5.

Comment: See if this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118398/auto-increment-an-id-with-a-string-prefix-in-oracle-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto increment an ID with a string prefix in oracle sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118398/auto-increment-an-id-with-a-string-prefix-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take advantage of the appropriate [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) for TO_CHAR.

```
CREATE  SEQUENCE test_sequence START WITH 99 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999 NOCYCLE NOORDER;
CREATE TABLE test_table(pk varchar(32) primary key);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('YOURPREFIX' || TO_CHAR(test_sequence.nextval,'00009'));
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('YOURPREFIX' || TO_CHAR(test_sequence.nextval,'00009'));
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e16b/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest another, maybe simpler option - a **row generator technique**. It would be just fine to get you started as you said you have to insert "n" rows, now; though, if this is not a one-time-action, then yes - a sequence would be a better idea. Anyway, consider my `LPAD` suggestion.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id)
  2  select '10D' || lpad(level, 5, '0')
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= &n;
Enter value for n: 10

10 rows created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

ID
----------
10D00001
10D00002
10D00003
10D00004
10D00005
10D00006
10D00007
10D00008
10D00009
10D00010

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```